# Why does robocopy display some files as modified?

Tags: command-line, robocopy

I have 15+ data files I am trying to force overwrite with robocopy.  I use the following command line switches:

```
C:\>robocopy d:\datafolder f:\backup datafile*.dat /is /fft /MT:32
```

15 files copy successfully as expected.

I **immediately** run the following command hoping to see all 15 files targeted to be overwritten but 4 show a status of "modified" to be skipped.

```
C:\>robocopy d:\datafolder f:\backup datafile*.dat /is /fft /MT:32 /v /l
```

Here is the log of both executions:

> ```
> C:\>robocopy d:\datafolder f:\backup datafile*.dat /is /fft /MT:32
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>    ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>   Started : Thursday, December 22, 2016 11:35:45 AM
>    Source : d:\datafolder\
>      Dest = f:\backup\
>
>     Files : datafile*.dat
>
>   Options : /FFT /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /IS /MT:32 /R:1000000 /W:30
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> 100%        New File               1.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile0.dat
> 100%        New File               1.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile00.dat
> 100%        New File               1.4 g        d:\datafolder\datafile01.dat
> 100%        New File             600.0 m        d:\datafolder\datafile1.dat
> 100%        New File               2.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile11.dat
> 100%        New File               2.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile12.dat
> 100%        New File               2.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile13.dat
> 100%        New File             500.0 m        d:\datafolder\datafile2.dat
> 100%        New File             700.0 m        d:\datafolder\datafile3.dat
> 100%        New File             500.0 m        d:\datafolder\datafile4.dat
> 100%        New File             600.0 m        d:\datafolder\datafile5.dat
> 100%        New File             600.0 m        d:\datafolder\datafile6.dat
> 100%        New File               1.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile7.dat
> 100%        New File               1.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile8.dat
> 100%        New File               1.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile9.dat
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>                Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
>     Dirs :         1         1         1         0         0         0
>    Files :        15        15         0         0         0         0
>    Bytes :  15.882 g  15.882 g         0         0         0         0
>    Times :   1:57:36   0:09:00                       0:00:00   0:00:49
>    Ended : Thursday, December 22, 2016 11:45:35 AM
>
>
> C:\>robocopy d:\datafolder f:\backup datafile*.dat /is /fft /MT:32 /v /l
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>    ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>   Started : Thursday, December 22, 2016 11:45:50 AM
>    Source : d:\datafolder\
>      Dest = f:\backup\
>
>     Files : datafile*.dat
>
>   Options : /FFT /V /L /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /IS /MT:32 /R:1000000 /W:30
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>               modified           600.0 m        d:\datafolder\datafile1.dat
>               modified           500.0 m        d:\datafolder\datafile2.dat
>               modified           700.0 m        d:\datafolder\datafile3.dat
>               modified           500.0 m        d:\datafolder\datafile4.dat
> 100%        Same                   1.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile0.dat
> 100%        Same                   1.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile00.dat
> 100%        Same                   1.4 g        d:\datafolder\datafile01.dat
> 100%        Same                   2.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile11.dat
> 100%        Same                   2.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile12.dat
> 100%        Same                   2.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile13.dat
> 100%        Same                 600.0 m        d:\datafolder\datafile5.dat
> 100%        Same                 600.0 m        d:\datafolder\datafile6.dat
> 100%        Same                   1.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile7.dat
> 100%        Same                   1.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile8.dat
> 100%        Same                   1.0 g        d:\datafolder\datafile9.dat
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>                Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
>     Dirs :         1         1         1         0         0         0
>    Files :        15        11         4         0         0         0
>    Bytes :  15.882 g  13.636 g   2.246 g         0         0         0
>    Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
>    Ended : Thursday, December 22, 2016 11:45:50 AM
> ```

**Anyone know why those 4 files are showing as modified and therefore being skipped?**

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same thing. Are you copying files to a Windows server or a Linux (Samba) server?

Comment: Many years later but still looking for the answer to what exactly "modified" means. Something to do maybe with the archive attribute?

Comment: As [Rob Nicholson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288266/why-does-robocopy-display-some-files-as-modified#comment136731149_41288266) pointed out, it could be due to the Archive attribute. [Read more.](https://serverfault.com/a/943459/562269)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly problem is that these files are identical for robocopy - if timestamp and file size are the same robocopy will not copy/move files. To move or copy such files you have to add `/IT` option:

```
/IT :: Include Tweaked files - A Tweaked file is defined to be one that exists in both the source and destination, with identical size and timestamp, but different attribute settings.
```

Some links to read:

[How does Robocopy determine if a file is “changed”](https://superuser.com/questions/791053/how-does-robocopy-determine-if-a-file-is-changed),

[Robocopy Syntax, Command Line Switches and Examples](https://techjourney.net/robocopy-syntax-command-line-switches-and-examples/),

[What does Robocopy mean by tweaked](https://superuser.com/questions/314503/what-does-robocopy-mean-by-tweaked-lonely-and-extra)